# How to send push notification from Rest API

Tags: ios, rest, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created my App in `Firebase` and configured for cloud messaging.
When I am sending the notification from `Firebase` Console, device gets the notification but if I try to send via Rest API (Using PostMan). 
Then notification not coming to device but the response is showing as Success.

Here is my PostMan request

> URI - https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
>
> Header: Content-Type:application/json Authorization:key=MY_SERVER_KEY
>
> Body: { "data": {  "title": "Firebase",  "detail": "I am firebase" }, 
>   "to" : "MY FCM TOKEN HERE" }
>
> Response : {
>       "multicast_id": 7834540847388366233,
>       "success": 1,
>       "failure": 0,
>       "canonical_ids": 0,
>       "results": [
>           {
>               "message_id": "0:1532422122326299%ebf5f25ef9fd7ecd"
>           }
>       ] }

I have searched and it seems the way mentioned in documentation is same as I am following
Can anyone let me know why it is not working?
Thanks

Comment: you need to use "notification" key instead if "data"

Comment: @rv7284, Thank you. It worked..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting here so as to guide others. As per the guidance of @rv7284, We need to send the data in `notification` key rather any other key.

So While requesting the body should look like this, Other request parameter like header and all will be same as mentioned in the question.

```
{ "notification": {
 "title": "Firebase",
 "detail": "I am firebase"
},
 "to" : "YOUR FCM TOKEN"
}
```

Comment: As of this day, based on my recent testing,  "detail" key has been renamed to "text".