# FCM give success but Notification is not received by android device

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I try to send push notifications via a cURL request, the response from the server indicates that I was successful but the message isn't received on the device. I have tried this with both multicast and single recipient payloads.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
//API URL of FCM
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

/*api_key available in:
Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> CLOUD MESSAGING -> Server key*/ $api_key = 'API_KEY';

$device_id = 'eE5U0IQEyTo:APA91bGplai6Bf5ko1hlW5y0oLb0WIa5JytpcuZ7B9lbIay8PNfPv2i1HMUqg1hDtPQqvhy4KLIZgyEh0BHHkfJtdX7E0Ftm-OaN23VahOoWAzjNP2QK8Se7PCibhooVG71jMPmzTHqd';

$fields = array (
    'registration_ids' => array (
            $device_id
    ),
    'data' => array (
        "title" => "test from server",
        "body" => "test lorem ipsum"
    )
);
//header includes Content type and api key
$headers = array(
'Content-Type:application/json',
'Authorization:key='.$api_key
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === FALSE) 
{
die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
else
{
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($result);
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Here is the response I get when running this code:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 1338828245860499776,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [{
        "message_id": "0:1578484075615332%52ec0605f9fd7ecd"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Bug in android  side. does android dev have added proper code for receive notification?

Comment: also do not expose your `api_key` of FCM in stack overflow.

Comment: any solution so far??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51495856/894671

Answer (score 8):

Rename, "data" to "notification"

If the "notification" object is absent, the device will not show the notification in the drawer.

"data" is interpreted by the app

"notification" is interpreted by the device..

You can use both separately, but "notification" object is required if you want to show the notification.

[Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

Answer (score 5):

perfect answer @Chetan , with 'data' notification wont show, but with 'notification' it shows.

so your array should be:

```
$fields = array (
    'registration_ids' => array (
            $device_id
    ),
    'notification' => array (
        "title" => "test from server",
        "body" => "test lorem ipsum"
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem by removing the app and install it again.

Comment: This answer do not resolve the current problem. A re-installation from the application may not be solve the current issue, the most predictable scenario here is that the application contain some failing flow and can not receive the notifications coming from Firebase.